# How do I get the weapon of the heavy armored guards?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

When Ezzio is fighting and has no weapon equiped, he can get the guards' weapon with the "steal" command (square at PS3).

With some type of guards this always works, but with other types (like heavy armored guards) always fail. In that case, every time I try, Ezzio tries to take the weapon but the guard defends and counter with a kick.

How do I get the weapon of the heavy armored guards?

Comment: Uhhh ... Kill them and pick it up, I believe?

Comment: Well, the mission is to steal the weapon and kill the guard with his own weapon, so this is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some characters in the game that are more difficult to disarm (some are even impossible). Specifically for Papal Guards, you must:

1. Taunt at the guard
2. Let their first strike hit you
3. Before their second strike lands, perform a counter with empty fists

That should allow you to steal their weapon and kill them.